# How to turn part of the response from Dio into a variable in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Using Dio, I make a specific request to the site:

```dart
final response = await Dio().get(
…
print(response); //Just to see my response
```

Here is the response from the console:

```dart
I/flutter ( 4594): {"records":[{"id":"recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs","createdTime":"2022-07-28T15:45:23.000Z","fields":{"Name":"Cactus ","Data":"11.5","App":"The Best App","Current":"98789fg43"}}]}
```

I am satisfied with the data. They are correct. For further work, I only need the recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs value. I want to pass it to a variable that will be used in another part of the code. How to do it?

**Edit1.**
Using `var decodedString = json.decode(response.data.toString());` does not cause any errors in the code. But on startup, the following appears in the console:

```dart
I/flutter ( 4594): {"records":[{"id":"recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs","createdTime":"2022-07-28T15:45:23.000Z","fields":{"Name":"Cactus ","First":"11.5","App":"The Best App","Current":"98789fg43"}}]}
E/flutter ( 4594): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
E/flutter(4594): {records: [{id: recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs, createdTime: 2022-07-28T15:45:23.000Z, f...
E/flutter ( 4594): ^
E/flutter ( 4594):
E/flutter ( 4594): #0 _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
E/flutter ( 4594): #1 _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:913:48)
E/flutter ( 4594): #2 _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
E/flutter ( 4594): #3 JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
E/flutter ( 4594): #4 JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
E/flutter(4594): #5 _MainWidgetState.airtableFind(package:example/main.dart:214:32)
E/flutter ( 4594): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4594):
```

And here is the whole code in case I made a mistake somewhere:

```dart
//Airtable (find a record)
  void airtableFind() async {
    try {
      final response = await Dio().get(
        'https://api.airtable.com/v0/'+projectBase+'/'+recordName,
        queryParameters: {
          // 'filterByFormula': 'SEARCH("Cactus",{Name})' // Searches the value 'Cactus' in the {'Short description'} field.
          'filterByFormula': 'SEARCH('+'"'+testName+'"'+',{Name})' // Searches the value 'Cactus' in the {'Short description'} field.
          // 'filterByFormula': 'SEARCH('+testName+',{Name})' // Searches the value 'Cactus' in the {'Short description'} field.
        },
        options: Options(
          contentType: 'Application/json',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer'+' '+apiKey,
            'Accept': 'Application/json',
          },
        ),
      );

      // TODO: Whatever you want to do with the response. A good practice is to transform it into models and than work with them
      print(response);
      // String fromString = response;

      // String response1 = '{"records":[{"id":"recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs","createdTime":"2022-07-28T15:45:23.000Z","fields":{"Name":"Cactus ","Data":"11.5","App":"The Best App","Current":"98789fg43"}}]}';
      var decodedString = json.decode(response.data.toString());
      // final decodedJSON = json.decode(response.body);
      // final decodedJSON = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

      print(decodedString['records'][0]['id']);
      String id = decodedString['records'][0]['id'];


    } on DioError catch (e) {
      // TODO: Error handling
      if (e.response != null) {
        // print(e.response.data);
        print(e);
      } else {
        // print(e.request);
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Edit2.** When I use `final decodedString = json.decode(response.data);` I see the following errors in the console:

```
I/flutter( 4289): {"records":[{"id":"recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs","createdTime":"2022-07-28T15:45:23.000Z","fields":{"Name":"Cactus ","First":"11.5","App":"The Best App","Current":"98789fg43"}}]}
E/flutter ( 4289): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter(4289): #0 _MainWidgetState.airtableFind(package:example/main.dart:217:50)
E/flutter ( 4289): <asynchronous suspension>
```

When I use `var decodedString = json.decode(response.data.toString());` the following errors appear in the console:

```
I/flutter( 4289): {"records":[{"id":"recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs","createdTime":"2022-07-28T15:45:23.000Z","fields":{"Name":"Cactus ","First":"11.5","App":"The Best App","Current":"98789fg43"}}]}
E/flutter ( 4289): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
E/flutter(4289): {records: [{id: recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs, createdTime: 2022-07-28T15:45:23.000Z, f...
E/flutter ( 4289): ^
E/flutter ( 4289):
E/flutter ( 4289): #0 _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
E/flutter ( 4289): #1 _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:913:48)
E/flutter ( 4289): #2 _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
E/flutter ( 4289): #3 JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
E/flutter ( 4289): #4 JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
E/flutter(4289): #5 _MainWidgetState.airtableFind(package:example/main.dart:217:32)
E/flutter ( 4289): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json.decode to convert the response to a json value. Then you can fetch its values with respective keys like

```
String response = '{"records":[{"id":"recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs","createdTime":"2022-07-28T15:45:23.000Z","fields":{"Name":"Cactus ","Data":"11.5","App":"The Best App","Current":"98789fg43"}}]}';
  var decodedString  = json.decode(response);
  print(decodedString['records'][0]['id']);
//Output : recrNhzWnPdiSFaCs
```

Don't miss to import

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

Comment: This works perfectly in your example. But when I add this to my code, I get an error at the line ```var decodedString = json.decode(response);```dart:

```dart
The argument type 'Response<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (Documentation)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Use response.body

Comment: How exactly? I corrected this line to ```var decodedString = json.decode(response.body);``` But now I get the error ```The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>''. ```

Comment: I removed ```var decodedString = json.decode(response.body);```. But ```var decodedString = response.data.toString();``` causes errors in ```print(decodedString['records'][0]['id']);``` For example, ``` The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'```

Comment: Unfortunately this causes ```[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)``` and other errors in the console. I listed them all in Edit 1.

Comment: decodedString = json.decode(response.body.toString());

Comment: This causes the error ```The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>''.``` Can you take a look at the full code of my method in Edit1? Perhaps I should add something there to make the getter body appear. HTTP requests are a new topic for me. I see that you are well versed in this.

Comment: decodedString = json.decode(response.data.toString()); here its reaponse.data if you are using dio package and response.body.toString() if you are using http package

Comment: I'm using the Dio package, but I still get the error in the console that I wrote about in Edit2. What could be the reason?

Comment: I have already got an answer in another thread. It turns out that response.data is already decoded from JSON (It's a Map<String, dynamic>). So no need to decode it again with json.decode(response.data);. However, you pointed me in the right direction at the very beginning. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your purpose by decoding your JSON.

```
final decodedJSON = json.decode(response.data);
```

, also if your response contains a [UTF-8](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/what-is-utf-8) encoding (has for example Persian characters), you can use:

```
final decodedJSON = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
```

Comment: In this case I get the error ```The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>''. ```

Comment: Can you show me your code more specifically? you can update your question and show the approaches you've tried.

Comment: Yes, I have already posted the full code in Edit1. There are 2 variants: yours (this line is commented out) and Kaushik Chandru.

Comment: You should give response.data not response.body.

Comment: Thank you. Can you take a look at the errors in my console, please? I mean Edit2. I am using your variant, but the result is not at all what I expect. Still errors... What could be the reason?

Comment: Ok, now your problem is something else. your problem is in your castings. `String id = decodedString['records'][0]['id'];` this line has no direct casting and I think that's your problem. Change it to `String id = ((decodedString['records'] as List)[0] as Map<String, dynamic>)['id'] as String;`

Comment: I have commented out these lines to see if they cause errors. No, I still see the same errors in the console. But you're right. I have deviated from the original topic, so it's only right to create a new topic about the new error. Thank you.

Comment: I'll help you with your next question. don't forget to checkmark my answer if it helped you out <3

Comment: I have already created a new topic. I am not closing the current one just yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already got an answer in that thread. It turns out that response.data is already decoded from JSON (It's a Map<String, dynamic>). So no need to decode it again with json.decode(response.data);.

Answer (score 0):

dio body name is data so the decoding would be as following

```
final decodedJSON = json.decode(response.data);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you take a look at the errors in my console, please? I am using your variant, but the result is not at all what I expect.